# jQuery Menu Hover, but don't at click

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, html

HTML Structure:

```
<a class="fadeThis"  id="paperoff" href="#"><span id="paperon" class="hover">News</span></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.fadeThis > .hover').empty();    

$('.fadeThis').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).append(''+text+'');

    var $span = $('> span.hover', this).css('opacity', 0);  
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    }, function () {    
        $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
    }).click (function () {
        // HERE SOMETHING THAT TELLS TO NOT FADE BACK THE SPAN (ONLY FOR THE CLICKED DIV).
});

});
```

Comment: K sorry! The link is here: Laye.rs , when you click the upload button in the menu, I want that it keeps fade in and doesn't fade out! Because the upload is active!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but do you want someting like this?

```
var fadeBlock = false;
$(this).hover(function () {
$span.stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function () {
    if (!fadeBlock) {
      $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
} else { fadeBlock = false;}
}).click (function () {
   fadeBlock = true;
});
```